# Parsing a html from .txt file

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, download

so I got this code where I download a html, save it in a new created .txt file and then parse the file.
And i got a bug. everytime i change the path for the .txt file to download/create it, the first time i start the app i get a file opening error from my parse function.
But the second time i run it it all works well.

I have been doing some reading and it says that replyFinished() is  a place where code gets executed after the download finished, so i assume that is where i should call Do_parse(), but it aint working.

(gonna exclude the includes to keep it shorter)

.h

```
#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

class downloader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit downloader(QObject *parent = 0);

    void Do_download();

    std::string getExePath();

    void Do_parse(QNetworkReply *reply);

public slots:
    void replyFinished (QNetworkReply *reply);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    bool downloadSuccess;

};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H
```

.cpp

```
downloader::downloader(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    downloadSuccess = false;
}


std::string downloader::getExePath()
{
    char result[MAX_PATH];
    return std::string(result,GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, result, MAX_PATH));
}

void downloader::Do_download()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

            manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/hvazeca.htm")));
}

void downloader::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{

    if(reply->error())
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText(strings::msgBoxDownReplyError);
        msgBox.exec();
        downloadSuccess = false;
    }
    else
    {

        downloadSuccess = true;

    }

    if(downloadSuccess)
        Do_parse(reply);
}

void downloader::Do_parse(QNetworkReply *reply)
{

        QFile *file = new QFile(strings::filePathQt);
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();

        if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text))
            {
            file->write(data);
            file->flush();
            file->close();
        }
        delete file;

    reply->deleteLater();

}
```

.h

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H
    class parser 

{

public:
     explicit parser();

    QStringList currency_list;
    std::list<std::string> curr_list;

    void process_line(std::string line, std::map<std::string,double> &my_map, std::string curr_string);
    int read_line(std::map<std::string,double> &my_map);

private:

};

#endif // PARSER_H
```

.cpp

```
parser::parser()   
{
        init_list();

}
void parser::process_line(std::string line, std::map<std::string,double> &my_map, std::string curr_string)
{
    double curr;
    std::string temp;

    temp = line.substr(52,8);

    std::replace(temp.begin(),temp.end(),',','.');

    curr = std::stod(temp,NULL);

    my_map.insert(std::make_pair(curr_string,curr));

}


int parser::read_line(std::map<std::string,double> &my_map)
{

    std::list<std::string>::iterator iter;
    std::string linija;
    std::ifstream file_(strings::filePathStd);

    if(file_.fail())
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText(strings::msgBoxOpeningError); // this msg error pops
        msgBox.exec();
    }

    else if(file_.is_open())
    {
        while(std::getline(file_,linija))
        {
            for(iter=curr_list.begin(); iter != curr_list.end(); ++iter)
            {
            if(linija.find(*iter) != std::string::npos)
            process_line(linija, my_map, *iter);
            }
        }
        file_.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::map<std::string,double> currency_map;

    downloader d;
    d.Do_download();
    parser p;
    p.read_line(currency_map);

return a.exec();
    };
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your code is horrible. Do not mix STL and QTL. In one function you use QFile, in next std::ifstream. Use one at time.

2) Your error is pretty simple, it's basic async error.

The read_line() method will be executed before file is downloaded, because QNetworkAccessManager uses asynchronous API.

Simply put, when you invoke get() method - your application(main thread, actually) did not freeze until finished() signal is invoked - it continue working, while QNAM process requests in separated thread.

To fix it, you should emit signal at your Do_parse() method, which will invoke slot, in which you should run file parsing. So you need to create new class which will do all of this. Or just put

```
parser p;
p.read_line(currency_map);
```

in Do_parse() method.

3) You get memory leak in Do_download(), because you didn't delete QNAM. You should add:

```
reply->manager()->deleteLater();
```

at end of replyFinished() method.

Comment: Qt itself uses the STL, and [some](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qLess) functions are being deprecated in favour of STL equivalents, so "don't mix STL and QTL" is a bit over the top. Also, please consider that this error is not simple for OP, and telling them that it's simple and basic probably doesn't make them feel good, nor does it help them solve their problem/contribute to the quality of your answer.

Comment: I had to use to STL because of stl containters, but that's another story
Thanks for the reply, it is helpfull.
But if i could trouble you for another thing,
i created a std::map<std::string,double> &map; reference in my downloader class,
initialize it inline in the constructor, like this 
downloader::downloader(std::map<std::string,double> &my_map,QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), map(my_map)
i declared a ref on the map, initalized it,and im under the impresion everything is working with the SAME copy, but still its empty in my main.

Comment: @Mitch, yes, I know. But usually it's bad tone to mix it. Just look at any Qt application. Also I don't mean to offend anyone. If you write async code - this, probably, would be first error you encounter.

Comment: @puernos it's hard to read code in comments. It would be better if you create new question.